# Out of range in list,while parsing .csv file

Tags: python, file-import

I want to parse my .csv file.
In the logs, it's all right, I'm getting my first and the second value, but I have an error on the second value: Here is my code

```
    dec = attdecode.split("\n")
    line = 0

    for row in dec :
                line += 1
                rowparse = row.split(";")
                x=rowparse[0]
                y=rowparse[1]  # here, I GET : y=rowparse[1]IndexError: list index out of range
                print '//// rowparse', rowparse #I get all my line,with 4 elements divided by ;
                print 'x====', x #correct value
                print 'y===',y #correct value
                print 'Long===',len(rowparse) # I get 4 and it's correct
```

so if my y is correct, why I get an error on y=rowparse[1]

Comment: Can you provide an input example?

Comment: ANd the error Log?

Comment: You are using Python 2 i assume?

Comment: Aside from your problem, is there a reason to not use pandas to parse the csv?

Comment: yes it's python 2

Comment: In your example there is a ```Space``` not a ```new line```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works just fine for me

```
csv = "15717464674;Y5547;2;1\n14478878828;AB557;3;2"
dec = csv.split("\n")
line = 0

for row in dec :
            line += 1
            rowparse = row.split(";")
            x=rowparse[0]
            y=rowparse[1]
            print(x)
            print(y)
```